# KendoUi MVC Grid passing parameter values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a parameter value through to my controller method with no success.
The parameter value is coming through as null.

View Code:

```
 <div class="col-md-9">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("ProcessesGrid")
        .DataSource(datasource =>
        datasource
        .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("ListProcesses", "Process").Data("additionalData"))))
        <script>
            function additionalData() {
                //alert('Hitting javascript')
                return {
                    testParam: 2
                };
            }
        </script>
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListProcesses([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int? testParam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Kendo UI are you using? There was a bug in 2013.3.1316 which meant parameters from JavaScript functions are not sent with the request. This sounds exactly like your issue. The issue was with the kendo.aspnetmvc.js file. This was fixed in the internal build 2013.3.1321 and subsequent release 2013.3.1324 - both of these should be available to download in your My Account area.

Comment: Spot on! Upgrade to latest fixed the issue!

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.  I've downloaded the latest hotfixes, but still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your version number? Are you able to use something like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if the parameters are being sent. Have you updated your script files - especially kendo.aspnetmvc.js (or the minified version)? Are you calling a local function to return data for the request parameters? If so, have you checked if that function is returning data.